# DatePicker is working really weird in iOS react-native 0.60.6

Tags: react-native

Don't know when this happened because it used to work before, but it might be probably ever since I upgraded react-native to 0.60.6.
I tested 3 libraries thus far, and it's happening in all of them. Currently using [react-native-woodpicker](https://github.com/thodubois/react-native-woodpicker).

This is how it looks, it's all messed up:
[image]

Even though it shows no value where i'm standing at, there really is, you can literally feel the vibration when swiping up/down, but most of the times there is no value, you can swipe for like 10 seconds straight and all of a sudden the list of values will show up.

It's happening in all the DatePickers within my app, and only in iOS, Android works fine. So there seems to be an issue with DatePickerIOS.

Some code:

```
 <DatePicker
    onDateChange={this.handleDatePicker}
    date={new Date(this.state.user.dateOfBirth)}
    title={i18n.t('dateOfBirth')}
    placeholder={this.handleDatePickerPlaceholder()}
    placeholderStyle={scopedStyles.datePickerText}
    iosPickerMode="date"
    androidPickerMode="spinner"
    minDate={minDate}
    maxDate={new Date()}
 />

handleDatePicker = data => {
    var {user} = this.state;
    var thisUser = user;

    var date = this.getObjectFromDate(data);
    thisUser.dateOfBirth = data;

    this.setState({
        user: thisUser,
        dateObject: date
    });
};

getObjectFromDate(date) {
    return {
        day: date.getDate(),
        month: (date.getMonth()) + 1,
        year: date.getFullYear()
    }
};

handleDatePickerPlaceholder() {
    const {dateObject} = this.state;
    if (Object.keys(dateObject).length) {
        return `${dateObject.day}/${dateObject.month}/${dateObject.year}`
    } else {
        return `DD/MM/YYYY`;
    }
}
```

Any help given is appreciated.

Comment: that's the defsult date picker in iOS. how do you want it to look like?

Comment: No, you don't see it, there are huge white spaces, even in the photo above, the value selected which is December is not showing up. Now i see that if i don't set minDate and maxDate, everything is transparent, no value is showing at all.

Comment: In the photo, value should be December 7th 2004, and where is it? Also, i swipe and you can feel it's going through the invisible values, but just not showing up.

Comment: With minDate, all months are showing up except for December, then about days of the month, after Day 6, nothing is showing, there is space for those numbers, but not showing, the next thing you will see after swiping is going back to 1..2..3.., and for the year, nothing will be showing after 2003. Curious that my minDate is calculated by currentYear - 15 (2004) and today is Dec 7

Comment: Ohhh im also using iOS 13, this might be it too, i'm reading this on github about DatePickerIOS: @ffraenz DatePickerIOS is deprecated. Use https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-datetimepicker
If you will have same results, open issue there please.

Comment: OMG i found the reason, it was due to the "Dark mode" in iOS 13. I had to add a key into info.plist file.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is under the same problem, it's due to iOS 13's dark mode, thanks to [this guy](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/26299#issuecomment-540261084) on github, I was able to solve it.

The way to solve it is to add a new key/string value within info.plist file in your iOS app.

```
<key>UIUserInterfaceStyle</key>
<string>Light</string>
```

Hope this helps to others.